# Integrate Android and iOS libraries in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, jar

I want migrate my application to flutter, and i have now two versions (Android and iOS) of this application, for Android i have a third party library (Jar file) and for ios the same library (Framework file), the issue here is that i want to use flutter but i'm new with with it, so i want to know how to integrate the libraries for both plateforms, is there any way to do this ?

NB: The both libraries use bluetooth and for Android in addition we have Wi-Fi.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take flutter tutorial, you might just have to build from scratch with flutter

Comment: Take a look here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels